# How do I turn off the http appending to chrome's copy-and-paste URL

Tags: google-chrome, configuration

For the last few versions Chrome has stopped showing HTTP in the address bar. In addition when you try and copy a URL out of the browser window, the application automatically alters what it sends to the clipboard to add `http://` to the front of whatever I've copied.

Is there a way to turn this off anywhere? I'd like it to either display the `http` or send exactly what I copy to the clipboard.

Comment: This is not really a programming question... I second the motion though.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/503436/how-to-remove-http-adding-in-addressbar-of-google-chrome-firefox